# Trouble creating QWidgets programmatically

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

This program is supposed to create a collection of DraggableLabels in the central area by dragging from one of the provided labels on the left side.  Once they exist, they should be able to drag around and do different things when clicked or long-clicked.

[image]

Long-click works, based on a timer from MouseDown to MouseUp, but is not included here for clarity.

- MainWindow::test() works: It displays the icon like it's supposed to and I can interact with it.
- MainWindow::LabelMouseUp(..) doesn't work: It doesn't display anything and I can't seem to find it with the mouse.  The allScenes list does grow, so I know it's getting to that code.

Any ideas of what I'm doing wrong?  Specifically why the test() function works, but when I copy/paste its code into LabelMouseUp() where I want it, it doesn't?

I'm also open to a better way to do it.

---

Lights.pro:

```
#-------------------------------------------------
#
# Project created by QtCreator 2015-09-19T12:47:09
#
#-------------------------------------------------

QT      += core gui
CONFIG  += C++11

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = Lights
TEMPLATE = app


SOURCES += main.cpp\
        mainwindow.cpp \
    draggablelabel.cpp

HEADERS  += mainwindow.h \
    draggablelabel.h
```

main.cpp:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    new MainWindow();
    return app.exec();
}
```

draggablelabel.h:

```
#ifndef DRAGGABLELABEL_H
#define DRAGGABLELABEL_H

#include <QLabel>
#include <QMouseEvent>
#include <QEvent>

class DraggableLabel : public QLabel
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit DraggableLabel(QWidget *parent = 0);

    void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent* ev);
    void mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent* ev);
    void mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent* ev);

signals:
    void MouseDown(DraggableLabel* sender, int x, int y);
    void MouseUp(DraggableLabel* sender, int x, int y);
    void MouseMove(DraggableLabel* sender, int x, int y);

public slots:

};

#endif // DRAGGABLELABEL_H
```

draggablelabel.cpp:

```
#include "draggablelabel.h"

DraggableLabel::DraggableLabel(QWidget *parent) :
    QLabel(parent)
{
}

void DraggableLabel::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *ev)
{
    emit MouseDown(this, ev->x(), ev->y());
    ev->accept();
}

void DraggableLabel::mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent *ev)
{
    emit MouseUp(this, ev->x(), ev->y());
    ev->accept();
}

void DraggableLabel::mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *ev)
{
    emit MouseMove(this, ev->x(), ev->y());
    ev->accept();
}
```

mainwindow.h:

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QtWidgets>
#include "draggablelabel.h"

class ResizeFilter : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    ResizeFilter();

protected:
    bool eventFilter(QObject* obj, QEvent* event);

signals:
    void ResizeEvent(QSize size);
};



class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

private:
    ResizeFilter* filter;

    QPixmap* newPixmap;
    QPixmap* filePixmap;

    QWidget* pageScenes;
    QWidget* panelScenes;
    QWidget* panelSceneButtons;
    DraggableLabel* labelSceneNew;
    DraggableLabel* labelSceneFile;

    int panelwidth;

    QList<DraggableLabel*>* allScenes;

    bool mouseIsDown;

    QPlainTextEdit* debugLabel;

    QString IdentifyFunctionLabel(DraggableLabel* label);

    void test();

private slots:
    void FinishInit(QSize size);

    void LabelMouseDown(DraggableLabel* sender, int x, int y);
    void LabelMouseUp(DraggableLabel* sender, int x, int y);
    void LabelMouseMove(DraggableLabel* sender, int x, int y);
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

mainwindow.cpp:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"

ResizeFilter::ResizeFilter()
    : QObject()
{

}

bool ResizeFilter::eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent *event)
{
    if(event->type() == QEvent::Resize)
    {
        QResizeEvent* resizeEv = static_cast<QResizeEvent*>(event);
        emit ResizeEvent(resizeEv->size());
    }
    return QObject::eventFilter(obj, event);
}



MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
{
    filter = new ResizeFilter();
    installEventFilter(filter);
    showMaximized();    //do this before connecting so we miss the first resize event (wrong size) and catch the second (right size)
    connect(filter, SIGNAL(ResizeEvent(QSize)),
            this, SLOT(FinishInit(QSize)));
}

void MainWindow::FinishInit(QSize size)
{
    disconnect(filter, SIGNAL(ResizeEvent(QSize)),
               this, SLOT(FinishInit(QSize)));
    delete filter;

    allScenes = new QList<DraggableLabel*>();

    mouseIsDown = false;

    QString filepath = QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath();

    newPixmap = new QPixmap(filepath + "/Icons/New.png");
    filePixmap = new QPixmap(filepath + "/Icons/File.png");

    QWidget* centralWidget = new QWidget(this);
    setCentralWidget(centralWidget);

    pageScenes = new QWidget(centralWidget);
    panelScenes = new QWidget(pageScenes);
    panelScenes->setStyleSheet("background-color: darkgray");
    panelSceneButtons = new QWidget(pageScenes);
    panelSceneButtons->setStyleSheet("background-color: lightgray");
    labelSceneNew = new DraggableLabel(panelSceneButtons);
    labelSceneNew->setStyleSheet("background-color: darkgray");
    labelSceneNew->setPixmap(*newPixmap);
    labelSceneNew->setAlignment(Qt::AlignCenter);
    labelSceneFile = new DraggableLabel(panelSceneButtons);
    labelSceneFile->setStyleSheet("background-color: darkgray");
    labelSceneFile->setPixmap(*filePixmap);
    labelSceneFile->setAlignment(Qt::AlignCenter);

    debugLabel = new QPlainTextEdit(centralWidget);
    debugLabel->setReadOnly(true);
    debugLabel->setStyleSheet("background-color: white");
    debugLabel->setFont(QFont("Courier New", 7));

    int fullwidth = size.width();
    int fullheight = size.height();
        panelwidth = fullwidth/10;
    int buttonborder = 1;
    int buttonsize = panelwidth-(2*buttonborder);

    panelScenes->setGeometry(panelwidth, 0, fullwidth-(2*panelwidth), fullheight);                      //center area for user's canvas
    panelSceneButtons->setGeometry(0, 0, panelwidth, fullheight);                                       //button area on the left side
    labelSceneNew->setGeometry(buttonborder, buttonborder, buttonsize, buttonsize);                     //buttons on the left side
    labelSceneFile->setGeometry(buttonborder, buttonsize+(3*buttonborder), buttonsize, buttonsize);     //buttons on the left side (count borders from top, including one of its own)

    debugLabel->setGeometry(fullwidth-(panelwidth), 0, panelwidth, fullheight);

    connect(labelSceneNew, SIGNAL(MouseDown(DraggableLabel*,int,int)),
            this, SLOT(LabelMouseDown(DraggableLabel*,int,int)));
    connect(labelSceneNew, SIGNAL(MouseUp(DraggableLabel*,int,int)),
            this, SLOT(LabelMouseUp(DraggableLabel*,int,int)));
    connect(labelSceneNew, SIGNAL(MouseMove(DraggableLabel*,int,int)),
            this, SLOT(LabelMouseMove(DraggableLabel*,int,int)));

    connect(labelSceneFile, SIGNAL(MouseDown(DraggableLabel*,int,int)),
            this, SLOT(LabelMouseDown(DraggableLabel*,int,int)));
    connect(labelSceneFile, SIGNAL(MouseUp(DraggableLabel*,int,int)),
            this, SLOT(LabelMouseUp(DraggableLabel*,int,int)));
    connect(labelSceneFile, SIGNAL(MouseMove(DraggableLabel*,int,int)),
            this, SLOT(LabelMouseMove(DraggableLabel*,int,int)));

    test();
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{

}

void MainWindow::test()
{
    DraggableLabel* newlabel = new DraggableLabel(panelScenes);
    newlabel->setStyleSheet("background-color: darkgray");
    newlabel->setPixmap(*newPixmap);
    newlabel->setAlignment(Qt::AlignCenter);
    newlabel->setGeometry(200, 200, 100, 100);  //icons are 96 x 96
    connect(newlabel, SIGNAL(MouseDown(DraggableLabel*,int,int)),
            this, SLOT(LabelMouseDown(DraggableLabel*,int,int)));
    connect(newlabel, SIGNAL(MouseUp(DraggableLabel*,int,int)),
            this, SLOT(LabelMouseUp(DraggableLabel*,int,int)));
    connect(newlabel, SIGNAL(MouseMove(DraggableLabel*,int,int)),
            this, SLOT(LabelMouseMove(DraggableLabel*,int,int)));
    *allScenes << newlabel;
}

QString MainWindow::IdentifyFunctionLabel(DraggableLabel* label)
{
    if(label == labelSceneNew)      return "  SceneNew ";
    if(label == labelSceneFile)     return "  SceneFile";
                                    return "??unknown??";
}

void MainWindow::LabelMouseDown(DraggableLabel* sender, int x, int y)
{
    debugLabel->appendPlainText(QString("%1: Down:%2,%3").arg(IdentifyFunctionLabel(sender)).arg(x).arg(y));

    mouseIsDown = true;
}

void MainWindow::LabelMouseUp(DraggableLabel* sender, int x, int y)
{
    debugLabel->appendPlainText(QString("%1:   Up:%2,%3").arg(IdentifyFunctionLabel(sender)).arg(x).arg(y));

    if(!mouseIsDown)
    {
        return;
    }

    if(x > panelwidth)
    {
        QWidget* panel = nullptr;
        QPixmap* pixmap = nullptr;
        if(sender == labelSceneNew)
        {
            pixmap = newPixmap;
            panel = panelScenes;
        }
        if(sender == labelSceneFile)
        {
            pixmap = filePixmap;
            panel = panelScenes;
        }
        if(panel != nullptr)
        {
            DraggableLabel* newlabel = new DraggableLabel(panel);
            newlabel->setStyleSheet("background-color: darkgray");
            newlabel->setPixmap(*pixmap);
            newlabel->setAlignment(Qt::AlignCenter);
            newlabel->setGeometry(x, y, 100, 100);  //icons are 96 x 96
            connect(newlabel, SIGNAL(MouseDown(DraggableLabel*,int,int)),
                    this, SLOT(LabelMouseDown(DraggableLabel*,int,int)));
            connect(newlabel, SIGNAL(MouseUp(DraggableLabel*,int,int)),
                    this, SLOT(LabelMouseUp(DraggableLabel*,int,int)));
            connect(newlabel, SIGNAL(MouseMove(DraggableLabel*,int,int)),
                    this, SLOT(LabelMouseMove(DraggableLabel*,int,int)));
            *allScenes << newlabel;
        }
    }

    mouseIsDown = false;
}

void MainWindow::LabelMouseMove(DraggableLabel* sender, int x, int y)
{
    debugLabel->appendPlainText(QString("%1: Move:%2,%3").arg(IdentifyFunctionLabel(sender)).arg(x).arg(y));
}
```

Comment: Can you reduce your example to around couple dozen lines?

Comment: @AlexanderVX Given my inexperience with Qt (I'm used to VisualStudio and can't seem to make Mono work), I think that's going to be hard.  I already reduced it a lot from my main project.  Basically, the question is, "Why does this section of code work (MainWindow::test), but when I copy/paste it somewhere else, it doesn't (MainWindow::LabelMouseUp)?"  Everything else is there for context.  Sorry to make you wade through it, but I've run out of obvious things to trim.  If someone else wants to pare it down some more, then go right ahead.

Comment: Could you step through the code in a debugger to see where exactly it goes wrong and add those information to your question?

Comment: I know some of your code here is missing so I don't know if you are actually deleting these objects anywhere, but it seems `QList<DraggableLabel*>* allScenes;` is not deleted anywhere. In fact you allocate a new object every time there is a resize event, without deleting the old object. So you seem to have a memory leak there. There seems to be no reason to have this list as a pointer anyway, so you could just declare it as an automatic variable (`QList<DraggableLabel*> allScenes;`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your code my guess is that you should add something like show()

From the [Qt Documenation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#QWidget):

> If you add a child widget to an already visible widget you must
>   explicitly show the child to make it visible.

The reason why it works inside your test() function probabyl is that this code is executed before you even call app.exec().

```
newLabel->show()
```